# What type of wood should I purchase and how do I give it the shape I want?

Tags: wood

I want to refurbish a metal folding chair with seat and back cushions. The wood base for the seat and back cushion are in very bad condition and I have to replace them. I was thinking about using plywood for the seat base since the original one is flat. The back cushion base is curved though and I don't know what material to use to replace it.... The original looks like compressed wood. Is that what you recommend? How do I give it the curve I need? Thanks!

Comment: This is the kind of question that is so much easier to answer after seeing a picture of the chair. If you can't take a photo of your chair, post a link to a similar chair, perhaps in an online catalog. Some regular reader here with the needed rep can add the pic to your question.

Comment: This would probably get better answers at [woodworking.se].

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing the chair I wood go with cedar,its a little more expensive than most but will outlast all others resistant to insects and beautifull wood.